# magento2 : how to override lib/web/mage/adminhtml/browser.js?

Tags: magento2, javascript, overrides

I'm trying to override lib/web/mage/adminhtml/browser.js in my module.

here is my Company/CampaignPopup/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
map: {
    "*": {

        'browser':'Company_CampaignPopup/js/adminhtml/browser-custom',
        'adminhtml/browser':'Company_CampaignPopup/js/adminhtml/browser-custom',
        'mage/adminhtml/browser': 'Company_CampaignPopup/js/adminhtml/browser-custom'
         }
     }
};
```

I was trying all this paths.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try following code:

> 1. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/registration.php

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    '[VendorName]_[ModuleName]',
    __DIR__
);
```

> 2. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/etc/module.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="[VendorName]_[ModuleName]" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Theme"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> 3. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/etc/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Theme\Model\View\Design">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="themes" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="adminhtml" xsi:type="string">[VendorName]/[themename]</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

> 4. app/design/adminhtml/[VendorName]/[themename]/registration.php

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'adminhtml/[VendorName]/[themename]',
    __DIR__
);
```

> 5. app/design/adminhtml/[VendorName]/[themename]/theme.xml

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>Theme Title</title>
    <parent>Magento/backend</parent>
</theme>
```

> 6. app/design/adminhtml/[VendorName]/[themename]/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'mage/adminhtml/browser':'mage/adminhtml/custom-browser'
        }
    }
};
```

> 7. app/design/adminhtml/[VendorName]/[themename]/web/mage/adminhtml/custom-browser.js

Comment: Doesn't look like to work on Magento 2.4.2. Got static compilation error.